# Is iphone 3g and 3gs powerful enough to scroll full screen images

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a game with a whole bunch of tiles that are 320-480.  I want to scroll these by the user with nothing else but two png files displaying (about 100x100).  Is the iphone fast enough to do this type of scrolling?  What might be some of the limitations I would run into?

Comment: I suppose the two people who vote too localized are referring to Apple eventually phasing out these two models entirely. Remember that even iOS 5 works on iPhone 3GS, so this is going to be a valid concern for *at least another year*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iPhone 3G has only 128 mb of ram which may make it slightly skippy or glitchy but its lack of multitasking would definitely allow the game to run. The 3GS with 256 mb should be able to handle it no problem.

Answer (score 0):

If it can run [Infinity Blade](http://www.epicgames.com/infinityblade/), I suspect it can handle 100x100 tiles.